# How to put these 4 different form elements in one INPUT GROUP using CSS3?

Tags: css

I have 4 different elements which I want to show them in one INPUT GROUP. The problem is when adding "input-group-addon" everything collapses.

```
<div class="input-group" style="width: 100px;float: left;">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Quantity</span>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="proqty_redu" class="btn btn-default proqty_redu" type="button">-</button>
    </span>
    <input id="proqty" name="quantity" type="text" class="form-control" value="1" style="text-align: center;width: 50px; height: 39px;" size="2" numpass:type="+int">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button id="proqty_plus" class="btn btn-default proqty_plus" type="button">+</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for the same?

Comment: @AayushiJain: sorry, I didn't get the point. What do you mean?

Comment: Can you provide CSS also? And your question is also not that clear